# What is the PayPal PDT URL to retrieve transaction details?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm setting up [Payment Data Transfer (PDT)](http://www.paypal.com/PDT) in PayPal.

- After a purchase PayPal redirects the user to my return page and I have the `tx` parameter from the URL.
- I also have my `unique PDT token` from the PayPal profile settings page.

The documentation says the next step (step 3 in the diagram) is:

> Your return URL web page contains an HTML POST form that retrieves the transaction ID and sends the transaction ID and your unique PDT token to PayPal.

[image]

That's fine.

**But what is the PayPal URL that I POST this data to, to retrieve the transaction details? And what form / parameter names do I use?**

I've read multiple pages on the [PayPal documentation site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/) but can't find any reference to this PDT URL!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enable PDT via your PayPal dashboard, PayPal sends you a confirmation email. In this email is a link to, what appears to be, hidden documentation!

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

> Post a FORM to PayPal that includes the transaction ID and your identity token, a string value that identifies your account to PayPal. The form looks like this:

```html
<form method=post action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch">
  <input type="hidden" name="tx" value="TransactionID">
  <input type="hidden" name="at" value="YourIdentityToken">
  <input type="submit" value="PDT">
</form>
```

> In PayPal's reply to your post, the first line is SUCCESS or FAIL. A successful response looks like this, with the HTTP header omitted:

```html
SUCCESS
first_name=Jane+Doe
last_name=Smith
payment_status=Completed
payer_email=janedoesmith%40hotmail.com
payment_gross=3.99
mc_currency=USD
custom=For+the+purchase+of+the+rare+book+Green+Eggs+%26+Ham
...
```

*I initially discarded this email without reading it, which is why I missed the secret documentation!*

I also found [this stackexchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21634/paypal-pdt-and-ipn-how-does-it-work) which references a much older PayPal documentation page which says the same thing:

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/pdt-techview-outside

But again, the documentation page is not browsable, so you must happen to know the exact URL to find it!